# Typescript inference for unions not picking up the correct type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Apologies for the vagueness, but I can't use the original files for security.
I have four types:

**types.js**

```
export type BaseType =  {
  requestType: string;
  otherType: string;
};

export type TypeA = BaseType & {
  typeAThing: string;
  typeAOtherThing: string;
};

export type TypeB = BaseType & {
  typeBThing: string;
  typeBOtherThing: string;
};

export type AnyType = TypeA | TypeB;
```

**File.js**

```
import {AnyType} from './types.js'

export const File = () => {
  const thing:AnyType
  return (<div>{thing.typeBThing}</div>)
}
```

Throws an error:

```
Property 'typeBThing' does not exist on type 'AnyType'.
Property 'typeBThing' does not exist on type 'TypeA'.
```

Why is typescript not infering the correct type based on the structure of the two types it can choose from? I assumed that it would realise, TypeA does not have the property,  and then check TypeB and infer it as that. Am I missing something to help make it distinguish them?

Comment: well if `thing` is of type `AnyType` it could either be `TypeA` or `TypeB`. So accessing `typeBThing` is not safe because `TypeA` does not have this property.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following definition for `AnyType` to achieve what may be desirable...

```
//Either 

export type AnyType = BaseType & Partial<TypeA | TypeB>; // BaseType & here enforces fields from BaseType

// Or
export type AnyType = Partial<TypeA | TypeB>;
```

That should allow us to create a value(s) by selectively including fields from `TypeA` or `TypeB`.

With above type definition of `AnyType`, all of the following becomes a possibility...

```
const x: AnyType = {
    requestType: "string",
    otherType: "string"
}

const y: AnyType = {
    requestType: "string",
    otherType: "string",
    typeAThing: "A"
}

const z: AnyType = {
    requestType: "string",
    otherType: "string",
    typeBThing: "string"
}

const p: AnyType = {
    requestType: "string",
    otherType: "string",
    typeAThing: "A",
    typeBThing: "string",
    typeBOtherThing: "string"
}
```

---

### ***Limitation Due to Current Definition***

With given definitions, and having...

```
export type AnyType = TypeA | TypeB
```

Creating a value of `AnyType` is as good as writing...

```
const x: AnyType = {
    requestType: "string",
    otherType: "string",
    typeAThing: "A",
    typeBThing: "string",
    typeBOtherThing: "string"
}
```

Selectively taking out any field from `x` above will make `tsc` complain, as a `union`  entails all fields to be mandatory from either types(`TypeA` and `TypeB`) as all fields from either types are also **not optional** as per the provided type definitions.

If we want to leave any field(s) out, we will have to at least ensure that the value must satisfy completely that the resultant type of the value is either `TypeA` or `TypeB`.